# Cannot upload android app-release.apk to play store

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play

I have problem on upload my app-release.apk to play store, the apk is uploaded normal but when I upload during this week, play store take long time for review and reject my apk. Until now I cannot upload. I have search but the solution seem not specific. some solution with 64bit compliant

When I add this line to my gradle:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

and upload again still, play store still reject.

In my alpha play store I see this information:

> This release is compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.

I am using Android Native.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setting up your app to support 64 bits
here is the docs how to update your app
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

I recommend you read this post

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

Comment: I have tried already, and try many cases also but still cannot solve.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to not put the release .apk file into Play Store Console. Instead, generate a .aab file and upload it to Play Console and they will create an optimized version of .apk for you. It takes lesser time for them to review your release as well. 
Here you can find more details about it: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle